# Trouble with GridView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, android-gridview

My GridView Adapter, need add in gridView item only one picture

```
class GridPhotoAdapter(context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
    private var imageArrayList = arrayOf(
        com.example.b_my_friend.R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

    private lateinit var inflater: LayoutInflater
    private val context: Context = context

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return imageArrayList.size
    }
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return imageArrayList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return imageArrayList[position].toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var view: View = convertView
        if (inflater == null){
            inflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        }
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(com.example.b_my_friend.R.layout.item_grid_photo, null)
        }

        view.photo.setImageResource(imageArrayList[position])
        view
    }

}
```

and when i initialize in MainFragment

```
val gridPhotoAdapter = GridPhotoAdapter(activity!!)
gridPhoto.adapter = gridPhotoAdapter
```

i catch error i dont know why

gridPhoto must not be null

How solve this error?

fragment_photo.xml with my GridView(gridPhoto)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.page.PhotoFragment">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="30dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like gridPhoto is null. Are you sure it is not a null reference? Where do you set it up?

Comment: val gridPhoto = view.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gridPhoto) in MainFragment. add my XML with gridPhoto

Comment: And the onCreateView method? Maybe you are setting up another layout?

Comment: yea, its this, sry my stupid mistake)